# construct R data frame from audio file of sounds recorded from game app

Tags: discrete-signals, audio, audio-processing, r

I have an audio file (u8, 128kbps) of the sounds produced while playing a game app and clips of its three distinct sounds.​
​

The file consists of sequences of these, separated by silences, indicating next move (0.5 sec), correct move (0.5 sec, immediately followed by next move), and game over (5 sec).​
​

I want to construct a data frame with a row for each move and columns containing game count, duration in seconds, and correct indicator.​
​

Can someone suggest how I can approach this? I have a reasonably adept understanding of R. I looked at tuneR and more or less ​have a ​grasp​ on​ ​​its functions.​

​
chatGPT has been frustratingly useless.

Comment: Hello Steve Dutky and welcome to Signal Processing SE. Could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve as well as a similar example showing what the sound file might look like?